# Peak detection in 2D array for realtime processing

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have a 10x510 numpy array. It consist of readings from a real-time sensor. I want to find the peak of all rows individually and create a 2d array telling the peak index in each row. Each row can contain upto 4 peaks
Currently I am executing this in for loop.

```
for idx,val in enumerate(i3):
    if i3[idx]>threshold and i3[idx]>i3[idx-1] and i3[idx]>i3[idx+1]:
        peak_indices=np.append(peak_indices,idx)
```

Is there any other way of doing this using numpy or scipy that could make it quick without for loop?

Comment: Consider using `np.where`, `np.diff`, `np.logical_and`. You can also read the Numpy tutorial on the Numpy documentation website to start with.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to know if there any code that performs row wise operation in a parallel way.  Because i have a sequence of steps following the code given in the question.  And there are no data dependencies in it. So any suggestion on how to do row wise parallel operation.

Comment: So, in your understanding, a peak of a 2D array is any value above the threshold that is higher than both neighbors? For [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0] with threshold 1, the indexes [5, 7] should be returned?

Comment: What is the expected result if no peak exists (e.g., [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....]) or the peak is at the start or end of the row (e.g., [25, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 37])? And another problem - numpy arrays should be regular. So, it the first row returns indexes [5, 9, 214] and the second row returns [42], how should the result be returned as a numpy array?

Comment: Yeah i found comparison with neighboring values bring correct results for peak detection.     A row would contain one to max 8 peaks in the middle of the array. No peaks would be present as first or last element for my case.  If there are no peaks then then returned numpy array should be empty. The readings are taken in ms interval. So its very less probable for different number of peaks in each row. The data looks like row1 [ 0 10 20 40 25 0] row2 [0 12 24 45 21 0]  and so on.